# Execute SQL script from command line

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, command-line, scripting

I need to alter a database using a batch file, for a simple example, drop a table. I´m using local SQL Express (SQL Server 2008 R2) with user `sa` and its password.

How would the bat file be?

How can I specify in the script the password and that I use in SQL Express?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Take a look at the `sqlcmd` utility. It allows you to execute SQL from the command line.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

It's all in there in the documentation, but the syntax should look something like this:

```
sqlcmd -U myLogin -P myPassword -S MyServerName -d MyDatabaseName 
    -Q "DROP TABLE MyTable"
```

Answer (score 68):

You can do like this

```
sqlcmd -S <server Name> -U sa -P sapassword -i inputquery_file_name -o outputfile_name
```

From your command prompt run `sqlcmd /?` to get all the options you can use with `sqlcmd` utility

Comment: providing a file name containing all my SQL queries is much more handy than providing the SQL query as command-line arguments.

Answer (score 40):

If you use **Integrated Security**, you might want to know that you simply need to use `-E` like this:

```
sqlcmd -S Serverinstance -E -i import_file.sql
```

Comment: I ran, sqlcmd -i filename.sql  and it connected local sql server with integrated login and ran script... so looks like it has default values

Answer (score 2):

Feedback Guys, first create database example live; before execute sql file below.

```
sqlcmd -U SA -P yourPassword -S YourHost -d live -i live.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an empty database in SQL server, then run this command.

```
sqlcmd -s ServerName -d CreatedDatabaseName -i ScriptFileName.sql
```

ScriptFileName should be with a complete path like "D:\Folder Name\ScriptFileName.sql".

You can also use -u and -p if you have userName and password in your sql server.

Answer (score -3):

First set the path of MYSQL in Environment variable-> System variables-> Click on Path-> Add -> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"

Open cmd-> navigate to the folder which has the sql script-> type as below ->
`mysql --user=root -p < employees.sql` -> Enter the password which was set during MYSQL setup-> hit enter

Done.

[CMD Screenshot after it worked form me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de1jl.png)

Comment: Question are about Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. Check question tags.