# .BAT File to Execute SQL Query (Backup)

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I have an SQL script which is as follows:-

```
   BACKUP DATABASE [**********] TO  DISK = N'G:\Super Sacred Databases\Orderwise Backup\20-04-2017-13-05.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'**********-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

On the server I wish to run a .bat file that i can schedule on windows task scheduler.

My confusion is, how do i write a .bat file to execute this query on the SQL Server?

I have so far tried to use this:

```
sqlcmd -U myLogin -P myPassword -S MyServerName -d MyDatabaseName 
    -Q ?
```

The problem is that is doesnt work at all for me, furthermore i have no idea what the -Q ? would be to run a specific query in SQL Server.

Furthermore im not sure exactly how to specify the Servername or Databasename in the fields required.

I know im new to this, but im trying hard.

Thanks in advance for your help!

CONTINUED -

Now i am working with this

```
sqlcmd -U s******a -P 0****! -S LPSERVER\ORDERWISE 
-Q "BACKUP DATABASE [********Live] TO  DISK = N'G:\Super Sacred Databases\Orderwise Backup\20-04-2017-13-05.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'******estLive-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
"
```

But it just doesnt seem to do anything just shows the cmd line in the CMD interface and does nothing more.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute SQL script from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737064/execute-sql-script-from-command-line)

Comment: Thanks, ill check that out now and remove my question if it solves the same problem.

Comment: No need to remove your question, SO does not mind duplicates: If you didn't find the other question, others might not find it as well. They might, however, find your question and the link there.

Comment: -Q is the query. so for instance -Q "select from DB where NAME='Frank'"

Comment: anyway, you say command is not working for you, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Do you not use SQL Agent? An Agent Job is the usual way of doing this...

Comment: I tried using SQL Agent but i think if im not mistaken Express Versions of SQL dont have an agent, i only think this is true because of utterly failing to activate the agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since BACKUP DATABASE can be executed in the context of *any* database, you can just skip the `-d` parameter.

The "server name" is usually the Windows name of the PC running the SQL server instance, optionally extended by `\InstanceName`, if you are not running the default instance of SQL Server. For the local PC, you can simply use `.` as the server name.

`-Q` contains the query you are executing:

```
sqlcmd -U myLogin -P myPassword -S MyServerName -Q "BACKUP DATABASE ..."
```

Comment: Does it Go "BACKUP DATABASE *DATABASENAME*"?

Comment: (1) Make sure your SQL script works when run in SQL Server Management Studio. If you need help with that, feel free to ask a new question. (2) Once your SQL script works, plug it in here: `... -Q "...my sql script..."`.

Comment: Also does the BACKUP DATABASE cmdlet allow me to choose the destination of the backup save or will it use the queries default?

Comment: @LewisMCT333: I don't understand your question. You write `TO  DISK = N'G:\Super Sacred Databases\Orderwise Backup\20-04-2017-13-05.bak'`... is this not where you want your backup to be saved?

Comment: The SQL script i have in my initial post works perfectly. I guess that should do the trick then.

Comment: I didnt realise you could explicitly run SQL code in CMD using cmdlet, dumb me. That makes life easier. Is there a way to add some conversation between the backup SQL function to show that it is processing so you can see that on the CMD screen so it doesnt look like its just hanging?

-Correction it does just hang and doesnt appear to work... No errors though, just shows the script in the CMD line.

Comment: @LewisMCT333: (1) The "GO" shouldn't be necessary. (2) Please, no line breaks in your batch file!